# "effective" in sentence

Tags: grammar

Can you please tell me which one is grammatically correct and why ?

1- He issued the certificate effective as of/from April 2015.

2- He issued the certificate being effective as of/from April 2015.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 1, with "as of", is correct. The "as of" is optional: you could just say, "He issued the certificate effective April 2014."

If a document or status has no particular end date, we usually say that it is effective "as of" the start date. If it does have an end date, then we say "from" and "to" or "from" and "through". Like, "The certificate is effective from April 2014 to March 2015." But it's not necessarily wrong to shuffle the words round. "... effective as of April 2014 through March 2015" would be unusual but not jarring.

We don't normally say "being effective" in this context unless it's in a subordinate clause. Like you might say, "The certificate, being effective as of April 2014, is not relevant to the incident under discussion, as that took place in March 2014."

You could say "being effective" if describing a state of having impact. Like, "You know you are being effective when you start to make enemies." You'd rarely use such a sentence to describe the "start date" of a document, but maybe with some effort you could come up with a plausible example. Hmm, like, "There used to be a 30 day delay between issuance of the certificate and the effective date, but now they are being effective the day they are issued." Awkward, I doubt anyone would really say it that way, but maybe something of that sort.

Answer (score 2):

(AmE)

Number 2 is definitely wrong.  "being" is not needed.

Number 1 is better. It could, I believe, be improved by a comma, and by using "as of" a specific date ("as of April" is vague.)

"effective from..." is rare in AmE.

- He issued a certificate, effective **as of April 1, 2015**.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example where you have to use "being effective". thanks.

Comment: Hmm, whether "as of April" is vague depends on how precise a time is needed in context. In some cases it might be necessary to give a precise time of day, like "as of 8:15 am on April 4, 2015". But discussion of, say, a new work schedule might make most sense if we say it applies beginning in a particular month as opposed to a day, as it applies to all work days in the month.

Comment: The OP asks for a grammatical explanation but your answer does not give one. As I read it, you are only stating what might be considered proper usage or not.